# How to evalute the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\phi(n)}{2^n -1}$?

Tags: number-theory

In the above question $\phi$ is Euler's phi-function. This problem belongs to IMO shortlist.
All my efforts doesn't lead to any good result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{2^n-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\phi(n)2^{-mn}=\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{-n}\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)=\sum_{n\geq 1}n2^{-n}=\color{red}{2}.$$

Comment: Nice,+1,I think this IMO shortlist background is Lambert series,see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series

Comment: I didn't know about Lambert series. Nice answer.Can we solve the problem without using Lambert series?